# How to find bold characters for each line using Word JS API

Tags: office-js

I have a Word document and need to convert it into html by the following rules.

- Numbers need to add `<a>` tags
- Bold abbreviations need to add `<strong>` tags
- Add <h1,2,3> tag if paragraph has heading1,2,3 stlye

So far, I've done the `<a>` and `<h1,2,3>` tags, but bold abbreviations are randomly appear in the document. So how can I get these bold characters and add `<strong>` tag?

[image: sample docx]

```
let ps = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    const regex = /, \d+/g;
    ps.load("text, style, font/bold");
    await context.sync();
    ps.items.forEach((p) => {
      let newLine = "";
      return context.sync().then(function () {
        // If current line match regex: ", number", then add <a> tag
        if (p.text.match(regex) != null) {
          let matches = p.text.match(regex);
          let pageNumber = matches[matches.length - 1].substring(2);
          newLine = p.text.replace(regex, ", <a href=../../week01/" + pageNumber + ".html>" + pageNumber + "</a>");
          // p.insertText(newLine, "Replace");
          context.sync();
        } else {
          newLine = p.text;
        }
        ///////////////////////////
        // Another loop here ? 
        // How should I use 'font/bold' to find the bold characters for each line?
        ///////////////////////////
      });
      // ... add style tag e.g.<h1,2,3> then combine into html_final
    });
    await context.sync();
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this: use the [Paragraph.getTextRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview#getTextRanges_endingMarks__trimSpacing_) to split your sentence. then read the [Range.Font.bold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#font) property of the range object that is returned.

Here is a sample snippet:

```js
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    paragraphs.load();
    return context.sync()
      .then(() => {
        let ranges = paragraphs.items[0].getTextRanges([' ']);
        ranges.load("text, font/bold");
        return context.sync()
          .then(() => {
            ranges.items.forEach((range) => {
              console.log(range.text);
              console.log(range.font.bold);
            });
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: See also this sample which does something similar: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-MarkdownConversion

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no space between number and bold character and some bold texts are next to symbols. I'll try to do it with getOoxml() or getHtml(). The company PC am working with can only run 'script lab' add-ins, which is annoying.